# Noto CJK font not usable with ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, luatex, context

[Noto CJK](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/) font is an OpenType CJK font developed by Google and Adobe.

In ConTeXt, if I write

```
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [serif] [Noto Serif CJK SC]
```

then `context` will hang on loading the Noto font. It complains:

```
loading of table 'vorg' skipped
invalid index in single format 1: 64605 -> 67219 (max 65535)
rule 1 in gsub lookup 's_s_5' has empty lookups
```

Then it prints nothing. The memory usage rapidly rises to several GB. I had to manually kill the program.

However the font works well with XeTeX or LuaTeX alone. What is the proper way to make it work with ConTeXt?

Comment: That's a known problem.  There was something on the mailing list just recently: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/092669.html  ConTeXt hangs because it has to build those enormous font caches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works without a problem for me.  However, building the caches takes 50% of my RAM which is 8 GB!

This is the [official statement by Hans](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/092703.html) about the situation

> these fonts are huge ... and memory usage in lua can be large as 
>   allocations doubles when more is needed, but in the end the font gets 
>   stored quite efficient in the cache, so it's a one-time memory usage

I'm using `mtxrun` to build the font caches:

```
$ mtxrun --script font --convert NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular.otf 
otf reader      | loading of table 'vorg' skipped
otf reader      | invalid index in single format 1: 64605 -> 67219 (max 65535)
otf reader      | rule 1 in gsub lookup 's_s_5' has empty lookups
otf reader      | merging 3 steps of 'gpos_single' lookup 'p_s_2'
otf reader      | merging 4 steps of 'gpos_pair' lookup 'p_s_3'
otf reader      | turning pairs of step 1 of 'gpos_pair' lookup 'p_s_3' into kerns
otf reader      | merging 7 steps of 'gpos_single' lookup 'p_s_4'
otf reader      | merging 3 steps of 'gpos_single' lookup 'p_s_5'
otf reader      | merging 2 steps of 'gpos_pair' lookup 'p_s_6'
otf reader      | merging 5 steps of 'gpos_single' lookup 'p_s_7'
otf reader      | 18 steps of 343 removed due to merging
otf reader      | 1 steps of 343 steps turned from pairs into kerns
otf reader      | adding soft hyphen
otf reader      | duplicates: 1 :   (U+02003) @ I00574 　 (U+03000)
[...snip...]
otf reader      | duplicates: 1 : ➡ (U+027A1) @ I0053A ⮕ (U+02B95)
mtx-fonts       | font: 'NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular.otf' saved as 'noto serif cjk sc.lua'
```

Also running with ConTeXt works fine.  Here is a MWE:

```
\definefont[noto][file:NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular.otf]
\starttext
\noto 樂
\stoptext
```

[image]

The first run takes 50 seconds and eats 8GB of RAM, but the successive runs take less than 2 seconds and only a few MB of RAM.

If you don't have enough memory, try [downloading more RAM](https://downloadmoreram.com/).

Comment: I have no idea what the symbol means. I hope it's not insulting.

Comment: Thanks. It's a traditional Chinese character meaning "joy, happiness" :)

Comment: @user2249675 Phew, got lucky on this one :)  Because the memory consumption is so huge, you might be interested in section 9.2.1 “Trimming fonts“ in [Fonts out of ConTeXt](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf).